# Jquery Tablesorter not working! What's wrong with that?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm new to Jquery and I'm trying to use Jquery Tablesorter plugin and I've tested it in a simple html file as below but it is not working. All I have seen in browser is only a plain table with no sorting, none clickable header, it doesn't look like what I seen on Jquery Tablesorter home page. I don't know what's wrong with my html. I have placed 2 jquery files in same folder with this html file. Please advise!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
         $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there not a css file to include as well?

Comment: I would also check your browser console and make sure those files are loading in (just to be sure)

Comment: @leppie Yes, I have include default theme css

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle link of your code so we can play with it?

Comment: @Dead Man Yes, please sir. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/twentyle/BKgue/

Comment: @TwentyLe just check my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the working fiddle link. You forgot to add the `tablesorter js` and `tablesorter css` which I added in external resources in jsfiddle. You can check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/BKgue/2/

Comment: Okay, I have understood, fixed and that's worked now :). Thanks sir and thanks SO!

Comment: Where is the documentation that states you need to have tablesorter js and tablesorter css files?

Comment: Yeah I read the whole documentation, there is no reference AT ALL about having to add tablesorter.css for it to work. makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Which css do you need to include ? jq.css or style.css ? or both ? I can't get it to work...

Comment: @Laurent I was struggling with this for ages too after I had read everyones comments here. Then I realised I was still using <td> instead of <th> in the <thead>. Perhaps you have the same issue?

Comment: @MeltingDog I had an issue with the import of the css, now it's OK ! Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: I had this issue and realized my table was lacking both the <thead> and <tbody> elements.  Once I added them things started working properly.

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out that I had missed to use the thead and tbody html tags in my table. Apparently tablesorter is dependent on them.

Answer (score 4):

Notice `<th>` inside `<tr>` instead of `<td>` this was what prevented it from working for me.

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>column 1</th>
    <tr>
</thead>
```

Also the css is not needed for the tablesorter to work. If you want to keep your own formating but you want the little arrows to show, you just need the following code. and copy paste the 3 arrow gif provided by tablesorter into the same folder as the css file. or your own arrows gif if you want.

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
```